# Does the breed of a feline influence the house of an excellent Cat like it does for dogs in Pugmire?

Tags: character-creation, monarchies-of-mau, realms-of-pugmire

Welcome to the Royal Lands of the [Monarchies of Mau](https://www.realmsofpugmire.com/monarchies-of-mau), traveller! Here, the cats reign, and most belong to the Houses Angora, Cymrik, Korat, Mau, Rex, and Siberian, or any of the smaller noble houses that make up The Shadow Bloc. Here the cats follow callings like Champion, Footpad, Mancer, Minister, Tracker, or Wanderer.

But, dear friend, I fail to find out what breeds form those houses! I mean, let's assume there's a Maine Coon by the name of Rum Tum Tugger and he is a mercurial wandering Common Folk. Or there's Mister Mistoffelees, a Mancer, and Scholar in his own right wearing his black and white tuxedo coat with pride. But... Does their coat or breed actually have any meaning for the choice of the House they swear allegiance to?

In the *other* game, the one about these slobbering *dogs*, who claim the [Realms of Pugmire](https://www.realmsofpugmire.com/buy), each of their *breeds* is forced to one or another category. Like all Chihuahua are *Companions* (what a horrible unauspicious name!) and all Collies are *Herders*. Yet... I can't find anything like that or against that in this *clearly superior* book about the felines of Mau. In fact, I only find two times the word Coon, and both are in the credits of glorious cats.

Comment: Could you add a tag description for these two new tags? Otherwise they'll age away and vanish. Tags get kept if they have 2+ questions or 1+ and a tag descirption.

Comment: @doppelgreener There you go! stubs, starters, but something to work on!